# Php Connection sqlsrv_connect()?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

In no way do not know why I did not solve the problem 
Despite so much to do my research did not reach a conclusion 
Perhaps there is a solution that can help you solve problems.

My problem is: What's the reason I can not make the connection.

```
<?php

$server = "TOSHIBA";

$baglantiBilgi = array("Database"=>"test");
$baglan = sqlsrv_connect($server, $baglantiBilgi);

if($baglan){
    echo "Baglanti saglandi.<br />";
}else{
    echo "baglanti yok.<br />";
    die( '<pre>'.print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true).'</pre>');
}
?>

//baglanti yok.
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
            [1] => -49
            [code] => -49
            [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
            [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => IM002
            [SQLSTATE] => IM002
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Veri kaynağı adı bulunamadı ve varsayılan sürücü belirtilmemiş
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Veri kaynağı adı bulunamadı ve varsayılan sürücü belirtilmemiş
        )
    )
```

What is the problem please help me in this regard.

Comment: Install Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client.

Comment: ah thank you menn !!! JAY BHATT

Answer (score 0):

As Jay Bhatt already commented, this is the answer:

Install [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065#SNAC).